# Are MIME headers encrypted in an AS2 message?

Tags: biztalk, actionscript-2, mime

I read in the IETF AS2 spec here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4130.txt
That "EDI envelope headers are encrypted."

But I'm trying to determine if the MIME headers are encrypted. If I turn on WireShark, will I be able to read the MIME headers?

Reason is that in BizTalk 2016 we seem to be missing one of the headers, so I need to see in raw format if the trading partner sent it or not. The field I'm looking for is X-Cyclone-True-Receiver sent by an Axway software program.

(Related question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/543147b1-d38d-4a74-89b5-085d52e353bf/as2-promoted-field-xcyclonetruereceiver?forum=biztalkediandas2)

Answer (score 0):

Reading this [Structure of an AS2 Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/as2-messages#structure-of-an-as2-message) documentation.  I would say, yes, the MIME headers are encrypted if you set the encryption option.

e.g.

```
Encrypted, No compression, No signature = HTTP, AS2, MIME Header CMS-PKCS7 MIME Encryption EDI/XML Payload (encrypted)
```

The HTTP and AS2 headers are not encrypted unless you go via HTTPS protocol

Comment: I think I asked the wrong question.  I did finally use Wire Shark, and I'm able to see the HTTP headers above the encrypted data.  So I meant to ask about HTTP header, not MIME headers.

Comment: Yes, the HTTP headers are not encrypted.